# Yii2 temporary validation variable for model rules

Tags: php, validation, model, yii2, rules

I want to validate that `title_clean` is unique and can be used as an identifier for URL's. But it is just an temporary instance of the real public variable that is given through the input (REST here).

So I tried it with the following:

```
public $title;
public $title_clean // not set through a form it shall be temporary

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['title_clean', 'default', 'value' => $this->title],
        ['title_clean', 'clean'],
        ['title_clean', 'unique', 'targetClass' => 'Jobs', 'targetAttribute' => 'title_clean', 'message' => 'The title was already taken.'],
        [...]
    ];
}

 /**
 * Cleaning Method
 *
 * @return mixed|string
 */
private function clean()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $string) {
        $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
        $specials = array("/ä/","/ö/","/ü/","/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/","/ß/");
        $replace = array("ae","oe","ue","Ae","Oe","Ue","ss");
        if (empty($clean)) {
            $clean = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', preg_replace($specials, $replace, $string));
        } else {
            $clean .= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', preg_replace($specials, $replace, $string));
        }
    }
    return $clean; // Removes special chars.
}
```

but it does not validate neither throw out an error. Does anyone has an idea about it?

Comment: is this part of the rules() method?? you cannot add variables like this to the rules , rules apply only to the model fields (which are part of the db).

Comment: Yes it is part of the rules method. There is also a field in the DB for `title_clean`. I just do not want to get it with an extra param that is sent to the model. I want to generate the content for the db's field `title_clean` on the fly.

Comment: Then you are looking in the wrong place. Best is to modify your controller's create method `actionCreate()` and add this field there ?

Comment: What is 'clean' in the second rule? A model method, a class? And what do you mean with 'does not validate'? Do you get a validation error? And is title_clean really temporary if it is also present in db? Could you make things clearer and update your post, please?

Comment: I updated it. The rules succeed because `title_clean` is not set through the validation temporary. So in the first: he says okay it can be default, in the second: okay it can be cleaned and in the third: well yes an empty `title_clean` does not exist in the db. There is no entry in the db. This script just makes inserts and the `title_clean` is part of the Active Record that fills the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline validation is your problem. According to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators) for your second rule you would need a validating method like this:

```
public function clean($attribute, $params)
{
    $this->$attribute = self::do_the_clean_up_things($value);
}
```

and the clean method:

```
private static function do_the_clean_up_things($string)
{
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    $specials = array("/ä/","/ö/","/ü/","/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/","/ß/");
    $replace = array("ae","oe","ue","Ae","Oe","Ue","ss");
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', preg_replace($specials, $replace, $string));
}
```

Untested. I hope this is correct.